# How to get no of selected days in ngbootstrap daterange picker Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using ng-bootstrap for datepicker in my angular 2 app.
I have configured date range picker in my app.

HTML Template:

```
 <ngb-datepicker #dp (select)="onDateSelection($event)" 
 [displayMonths]="displayMonths"  [navigation]="arrows" [dayTemplate]="t" 
 outsideDays="hidden">
</ngb-datepicker>


 <ng-template #t let-date let-focused="focused">
        <span class="custom-day"
              [class.focused]="focused"
              [class.range]="isRange(date)"
              [class.faded]="isHovered(date) || isInside(date)"
              (mouseenter)="hoveredDate = date"
              (mouseleave)="hoveredDate = null"
             >
          {{ date.day }}
        </span>
      </ng-template>
```

TS file:

```
import { NgbDate, NgbCalendar } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

I need to get no of days selected in the datepicker.

Is there any way to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert toDate and fromDate to javascript Date Object, get the "Time" and divide by 24*60*60*100

```
this.days=(new Date(this.toDate.year+'-'+this.toDate.month+'-'+this.toDate.day).getTime()
    -new Date(this.fromDate.year+'-'+this.fromDate.month+'-'+this.fromDate.day).getTime())
    /(24*60*60*1000)
```

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8piuzf?file=app/datepicker-range.ts

Comment: Working Fine.Thanks